# How to download a binary file with HTTP::UserAgent

Tags: http, raku

I'm trying to download a file using `HTTP::UserAgent`, but all my attempts thus far have ended with the following error.

```
Malformed UTF-8
```

I've tried to use the `getstore` sub, exported in the `:simple` subset.

```
getstore($upstream ~ %module<link>, $dist.absolute);
```

And using the `HTTP::UserAgent` class directly.

```
my $ua = HTTP::UserAgent.new;

$dist.spurt: $ua.get($upstream ~ %module<link>).content;
```

While looking through [the source code](https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent) of the module, I [found a `:bin` argument for `.get`](https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent/blob/06a70d5cc8905dd5c5e16f26c8ca8cc1ad85f369/lib/HTTP/UserAgent.pm6#L100), so naturally I've tried that as well.

```
$dist.spurt: $ua.get($upstream ~ %module<link>, :bin).content;
```

But even with the `:bin` argument I get the `Malformed UTF-8` error.

How would I go about downloading a binary file using `HTTP::UserAgent`?

**EDIT**: To give some more context, the `$dist` is just another `IO::File` object, created with `tempdir.IO.add("dist.tar.gz")`. I've also tried to `.open` this file and `.spurt` to the `IO::Handle` instead of the `IO::File`, but this returned the same error. Adding `:bin` to the `$dist.open` call does also not seem to have an effect.

```
with ($dist.open(:w)) {
    LEAVE { .close }
    .spurt: $ua.get($upstream ~ %module<link>, :bin).content;
}
```

The URL I'm working with in this particular case is `https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/V/VR/VRURG/Perl6/OO-Plugin-v0.0.5.tar.gz`, but it doesn't seem to be limited to this URL only.

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving what you expected (can't tell from example -- no url)? Is `$dist` a handle opened to an incorrect encoding for binary data (can't tell from example -- lacking code context)? https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent/blob/master/t/220-binary-content.t

Comment: FWIW, `getstore('https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/V/VR/VRURG/Perl6/OO-Plugin-v0.0.5.tar.gz', 'OO-Plugin-v0.0.5.tar.gz');` WJFFM.  Maybe you should provide a runnable minimal test case so we can see where it goes wrong.  And also check which version of `HTTP::UserAgent` you are using – I used 1.1.46.

Comment: Argh, after updating the module (`zef upgrade HTTP::UserAgent`) it does indeed work. I hadn't thought about trying that, thanks for the tip! Should I close or delete this question, as it seems it's not a relevant question to anyone who updates their packages from time to time?

Answer (score 2):

try the :bin option for the spurt routine. This works for me (with http)

```
'/tmp/test.tar.gz'.IO.spurt( $ua.get('http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/V/VR/VRURG/Perl6/OO-Plugin-v0.0.5.tar.gz').content, :bin);
```